# MathJax sometimes doesn't work in older-style duplicate links

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, mathjax

Take a look at [Showing $f'(x) = f(x)$ implies an exponential function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122165/427632):

[image]

The Mathjax fails in duplicate links on duplicate questions closed prior to February 2013 that include HTML escaped characters. [Confirmed by other users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57825114#57825114) to happen.

Comment: Is this specific to old questions where the duplicate notice used to be edited into the post, or does it happen with the new system too? There is nothing we can do to fix those old edits - they require manual editing or reopening and reclosing as duplicate to use the new banner system.

Comment: @animuson I'm not sure if it applies to newer questions; I can try to find an example to test

Comment: This occurs because the automatic edit from the Community user would incorrectly escape apostrophes into HTML entities instead of leaving them alone.

Comment: To everyone, note the specific example pointed out in the question, i.e., [Showing $f'(x) = f(x)$ implies an exponential function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122165/602049), has now been manually fixed.

Comment: Marking this completed because the specific example is fixed and this doesn't occur with new duplicates. If you stumble upon an old duplicate, you can just edit the post (they're a part of the actual post body).

Comment: @animuson I just closed a dupe on CGCC of a question with mathjax in the target title, and it displayed it properly, so it looks like this only applies to older questions

Comment: @animuson just nitpicking here. But seeing nothing was changed it can't be completed, this bug should either be by-design, or no-repro ;)